# How to get the user id who triggers the pipeline in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, pipeline

I am configuring a GitLab pipeline to build my project, in that I need a way by which I can retrieve the user id of the one who triggered the pipeline. Is there any default variable which could help me to retrieve that value. I did tried CI_PIPELINE_USER_ID but it didn't return anything.

Comment: GITLAB_USER_LOGIN is the username and GITLAB_USER_ID is the ID

Answer (score 3):

you can used:

- `GITLAB_USER_ID` - The ID of the user who started the job.
- `GITLAB_USER_LOGIN` - The username of the user who started the job.
- `GITLAB_USER_NAME` - The name of the user who started the job.

reference: [Predefined variables reference | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)